# A test of English for some

Tags: riddle

> At first, you will not object
>   That I am the case, matter and subject
>
> Change my third and I become
>   Noxious, venomous, even lethal to some
>
> Change my third again then the bars and inns of the city
>   Are the place where you'll find me, very likely.

What am I?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are a

> Topic

At first, you will not object / That I am the case, matter and subject

> "Case", "matter", and "subject" are all synonyms for TOPIC.

Change my third and I become / Noxious, venomous, even lethal to some

> Change the 3rd letter to X, the word is now TOXIC. As in poisonous.

Change my third again then the bars and inns of the city / Are the place where you'll find me, very likely.

> Change the 3rd letter to N, the word is now TONIC. As in gin & tonic water.

As for the title itself

> Change the 3rd letter to E. The [TOEIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TOEIC) is an English language test.

Comment: ninja'd... :( +1

Comment: ^ by 59 secs :D

Comment: What about the title :)? (hint: same trick!)

Comment: @IAmInPLS Clever, I didn't realize that was a clue.  I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are -

> Topic,Tonic and Toxic

At first, you will not object
That I am the case, matter and subject

> Topic can be a case, matter or a subject

Change my third and I become
Noxious, venomous, even lethal to some

> p->x gives Toxic -> Venoumous

Change my third again then the bars and inns of the city
Are the place where you'll find me, very likely.

> x->n Tonic -> A refresher like an alcohol which serves as a tonic.

Oh well the title:

> A test of English for some -> Test -> [TOEIC](http://www.examenglish.com/TOEIC/)